# Split String read from text file, passed into ArrayList, then displayed in JComboBox - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to take certain words from a text file and display them in a JComboBox.  I am trying to use the SplitString() method, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Currently the text file is like this.

Course Code - Course description - Examiner - Moderator

I am trying to split it so the JComboBox will only show:

Course Code - Course description

This is the code I am using (please excuse the mess and lack of best practice, I am new to this and trying to learn).

```
package messingwithswing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class ReportGUI extends JFrame{
    //Fields
    private JButton viewAllReports = new JButton("View All Program Details");
    private JButton viewPrograms = new JButton("View Programs and Majors Associated with this course"); 
    private JButton viewTaughtCourses = new JButton("View Courses this Examiner Teaches"); 
    private JLabel courseLabel = new JLabel("Select a Course: ");
    private JLabel examinerLabel = new JLabel("Select an Examiner: "); 
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2,4,4));  
    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    private ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();  


     public ReportGUI(){   
            reportInterface();
            allReportsBtn();     
            examinnerFileRead();
           // courseFileRead();
            comboBoxes();
     }        

     private void examinnerFileRead(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));

             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                 String getname = scan.nextLine();
                 String[] names = getname.split("-");
                 courseList.add(scan.nextLine());
                 String name = names[0];
                 String course = names[1];    

             }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
//      private void courseFileRead(){
//         try{
//             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));
//            
//             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
//                 courseList.add(scan.nextLine());
//             }
//             scan.close();
//         }
//         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
//             e.printStackTrace();
//         }
//     }

    private void reportInterface(){         
          setTitle("Choose Report Specifications");                   
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
          add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          setSize(650,200);
          setVisible(true);    
          setResizable(false);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
    private void allReportsBtn(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(70, 50, 70, 25));
        panel.add(viewAllReports);        
        viewAllReports.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){               
                new AllDataGUI();
            }
        });         
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }       
    private void comboBoxes(){                
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
        String[] comboBox1Array = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
        panel.add(examinerLabel);
        panel.add(comboBox1);          
        panel.add(viewTaughtCourses);
         viewTaughtCourses.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewCourseGUI();
            }
        });  
         String[] comboBox2Array = courseList.toArray(new String[courseList.size()]);
         JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox(comboBox2Array);
         panel.add(courseLabel);         
         panel.add(comboBox2); 
         panel.add(viewPrograms);
         viewPrograms.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewProgramGUI();             
            }
        });  
         add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

    }   

}
```

If you don't want to dig through the above mess, the code with the split method is:

```
 private void examinnerFileRead(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));

             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                 String getname = scan.nextLine();
                 String[] names = getname.split("-");
                 courseList.add(scan.nextLine());
                 String name = names[0];
                 String course = names[1];    

             }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
```

And the comboBox code is:

```
 private void comboBoxes(){                
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
        String[] comboBox1Array = nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
        panel.add(examinerLabel);
        panel.add(comboBox1);          
        panel.add(viewTaughtCourses);
         viewTaughtCourses.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewCourseGUI();
            }
        });  
         String[] comboBox2Array = courseList.toArray(new String[courseList.size()]);
         JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox(comboBox2Array);
         panel.add(courseLabel);         
         panel.add(comboBox2); 
         panel.add(viewPrograms);
         viewPrograms.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                 
                 new ViewProgramGUI();             
            }
        });  
         add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

    }
```

Comment: What does it mean it's not working? What values are you getting on name and course variables? You aren't adding them to any combobox...
The split is correct.

Comment: Is "Course Code - Course description - Examiner - Moderator" a single line in the file?

Comment: I mean it isn't splitting.  It is showing everything in the line.  So instead of showing course code course description, it is showing Course Code - Course description - Examiner - Moderator including the "-".

Comment: @Jeff Ward Yes it is.

Comment: try something like: comboBox2.add(name + " - " + course);
also not that you shouldn't be doing scan.nextLine() inside the while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm speculating which tokens belong to each list but you need something like this:

```
         while(scan.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scan.nextLine();
             String[] tokens = line.split("-");
             String code = tokens[0].trim();
             String description = tokens[1].trim();
             String examiner = tokens[2].trim();
             String moderator = tokens[3].trim();

             courseList.add(code);
             courseList.add(description);

             nameList.add(examiner);
             nameList.add(moderator);
         }
```

Comment: please edit to 
String line=null;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
so he doesn't read 2 lines everytime.

Comment: Seems to be throwing me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: @Splunk then your line doesn't have the format you suggested. Put a breakpoint on `String line` and make sure it is formatted like you show in your example.

Comment: @Jeff Ward That's the issue.  I hadn't actually added the moderator details to the text file.  Works well now.  Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @alscu where would I put String line=null; while((line=br.readLine())!=null){  because as you said, I am pulling in unwanted text.

Comment: @Splunk  I got mixed up sorry :P. The above solution is totally correct.

Comment: This is giving me duplicates in the name combobox and names as well as course data in the course combobox.

Comment: @Splunk Edit your question to include `Course.txt` so I have enough detail to highlight the problem.

Comment: I figured it.  I was missing a delimiter in the .txt file so it threw it out.

Answer (score 0):

The following fragment has several problems:

```
         while(scan.hasNextLine()){
             String getname = scan.nextLine();
             String[] names = getname.split("-");
             courseList.add(scan.nextLine());
             String name = names[0];
             String course = names[1];    

         }
```

1. You are reading **two** lines in one loop iteration, when the 1st goes into local array `names` and the 2nd is added to the `courseList`.
2. `names`, `name` and `course` are all **local** variables and not visible outside the method they declared in.